# How to validate params comming from GET request in Yii2 RESTful service

Tags: json, rest, validation, get, yii2

I have a `language` parameter that **needs** to be sent to my documents endpoint. So I have to validate that user has sent this parameter in his GET request.

Making rule in my model didn't do anything:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['language'], 'required'],
    ];
}
```

Because of that I have tried this:

1) I have created ParamsValidator class:

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\v1\components;

use yii\web\UnprocessableEntityHttpException;
use yii\base\Component;
use Yii;

/**
 * Class that is responsible for validating input params.
 */
class ParamsValidator extends Component
{
    public function validate($params)
    {
        if (!isset($params['language'])) {
            throw new UnprocessableEntityHttpException("Language parameter is required");
        }
    }
}
```

I am invoking its `validate()` method inside my controllers `init()` method:

```
public function init()
{
    $this->_params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;

    $validator = new ParamsValidator();
    $validator->validate($this->_params);
}
```

And this sort of work. Code works, but I get ugly response back. Instead of nice JSON response, I get bunch of html starting like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Unprocessable entity (#422)</title>
        <style>
        body {
            font: normal 9pt "Verdana";
            color: #000;
            background: #fff;
        }
```

Instead of this html, I would like some nice JSON response like this:

```
{
    "name": "Forbidden",
    "message": "You are not authorized to do this.",
    "code": 0,
    "status": 403,
    "type": "yii\\web\\ForbiddenHttpException"
}
```

This nice JSON error that you see is made by:

```
$behaviors['authenticator'] = [
    'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
    'auth' => [$this, 'authenticate']
];
```

But obviously my Validator is not doing this.

Questions:

1) How to validate params that comes via GET request ?
2) If my method is right, how to get this nice JSON error response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option is by overriding the [ActiveController::checkAccess](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller.html#checkAccess()-detail) method by adding this inside controller:

```
public function checkAccess($action, $model = null, $params = [])
{
    if ($action === 'index' or $action === 'view') 
    {
        $params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
        if (!isset($params['language'])) {
             throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('You are not authorized to do this.');
        }

    }
}
```

In case you need to do it at model level you'll need to use the [addError()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#addError()-detail) method instead of directly throwing the error. Your model instance will hold it when invoking its [validate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#validate()-detail) method. Then inside your action you can simply return it. it will be serialized and errors will be outputted in the right format. There is many ways to achieve this. A simple example may be by using the [load](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail) method to pass both query and body params to the model before validating it (scenarios may be required):

```
$queryParams = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
$bodyParams  = Yii::$app->request->bodyParams;

$params = array_merge($queryParams,$bodyParams );

$model = new $modelClass;
$model->load($params , '');

if ($model->validate() === false) return $model;
else {
   // do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: You are missing closing brace `if (!isset($params['language']))`. Anyway, this works, but why checkAccess and why ForbiddenHttpException ? It doesn't seem semantic to me to call parameter validation an access check. Or I am wrong ?

Comment: You can throw any kind of errors you need there the idea is that your error message will be serialized there as your controller's content negociator filter will apply. I'd personally do it at model level. check my update

Comment: OK, when I do this, I get the validation, and I get the error: `        $model = new $this->modelClass;

        $queryParams = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
        $bodyParams  = Yii::$app->request->bodyParams;

        $params = array_merge($queryParams,$bodyParams);

        $model->load($params, '');

        if (!$model->validate()) {
            return $model;
        }` but error is in format : `[
    {
        "field": "language",
        "message": "Language cannot be blank."
    }
]` and I would like JSON response like I have described in question. It need to have status

Comment: I have decided to use first method since I find it less bad for my current situation. I need to validate x models at onece based on how many I need to use to create response. I will rather keep validation logic in one place in my Validator class and just invoke it from base controllers checkAccess method. Thanks for help. I am pretty mush disappointed with yii2 solution for this.

Comment: both `UnprocessableEntityHttpException` and `ForbiddenHttpException` are `yii\web\HttpException`. at first I thought it was the contentNegociator responsable for that serialization but now as you did mention it I may be wrong in thinking it is the only way as the ForbiddenHttpException is directly thrown from the user class without going through controller. I'll check how it works when i'll be front of my computer at home. i'll update my answer if i find better solution. if someone else figure out better a answer. in this case i'd suggest selecting his answer instead of mine.